# Do E. coli change color (from white/grey to yellow) when they grow older?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

In my experiment, I had white colonies initially and they turned yellow. So I thought it´s natural that mature E. coli colonies are yellow and young are white. But it could be that I had two types of E. coli and the yellow one just dominated the white.

I research the affect of vitamin C on susceptibility of E. coli to H2O2.
First I treat bacteria with vitamin C, incubate for an hour and H2O2.

[image]
That is what I have on all of the plates. It really seems like there are 2 species present.

Comment: Can you please add more information about the experiment that you are doing?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could attach pictures of experiment results.